# Can't create table or database in sql server as permission denied in database master . (Logged in with windows authentication )

Tags: sql-server-2008

Can't create table or database in sql server as permission denied in database master. 
Log in authentication is Windows authentication (./SQLEXPRESS)

Comment: This belongs on Database Administrators SE.  Flagged for migration.

Answer (score 2):

In order to create a database, you need to either be a part of the `dbcreator` fixed server role, or have either of the following permissions on the server: `CREATE DATABASE`, `CREATE ANY DATABASE`, or `ALTER ANY DATABASE`.

The fact that you are using Windows Auth is a neutral point, as within SQL Server it is a principal that still needs the required permissions to perform the necessary actions.